# Can I load feature modules depending on productFlavors?

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to refactor Android application into multiple modules and include them in build depending on productFlavors?

Example: I have base application and 1 feature module. Now I want to build application 2 times. First time with base module and second time with base module and feature module. Can i specify this in productFlavors? and can i detect from source code if module is loaded?